# For any $n$-by-$n$ complex matrix $M$, prove that rank$(M)$ + rank $(M − M^3)$ = rank$( M − M^2)$+ rank$(M + M^2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

For any $n$-by-$n$ complex matrix $M$, prove that

$$\operatorname{rank}(M) + \operatorname{rank}(M − M^3) = \operatorname{rank}(M − M^2) + \operatorname{rank}(M + M^2)$$

In this problem, I could not find an idea to approach this. Any hint/idea will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know about the Frobenius rank inequality? I don't know if you're intended to use it, but it seems like you can use the equality case in said inequality to obtain the desired result with $B = M$, $A = I - M$ and $C = I + M$, though of course it'd only "push the goalpost" if you can't use the inequality. For reference: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497830/frobenius-inequality-rank and for the equality case: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/872587/equality-case-in-the-frobenius-rank-inequality

Answer (score 1):

One approach is as follows. Denote
$$
d_1 = \dim \text{Nul}(M)\\\\
d_2 = \dim \text{Nul}(M- I)\\
d_3 = \dim \text{Nul}(M + I)\\
$$
where $\text{Nul}(M)$ denotes the nullspace of $M$. Argue that
$$
\text{rank}(M) = n - d_1\\
\text{rank}(M(M - I)) = n - d_1 - d_2\\
\text{rank}(M(M + I)) = n - d_1 - d_3\\
\text{rank}(M(M - I)(M + I)) = n - d_1 - d_2 - d_3.
$$
From there, the conclusion follows.